# Changing column width from excel files

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, styleframe

I have a file like so that I am reading from excel:

```
Year  Month  Day
1     2      1
2     1      2
```

I want to specify the column width that excel recognizes.  I would like to do it in pandas but I don't see a option.  I have tried to do it with the module `StyleFrame`.

This is my code:

```
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel(r'P:\File.xlsx')
excel_writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(r'P:\File.xlsx')
sf=StyleFrame(df)
sf=sf.set_column_width(columns=['Year', 'Month'], width=4.0)
sf=sf.set_column_width(columns=['Day'], width=6.00)
sf=sf.to_excel(excel_writer=excel_writer)
excel_writer.save()
```

but the formatting isn't saved when I open the new file.

Is there a way to do it in pandas?  I would even take a pure python solution to this, pretty much anything that works.

Comment: This works ok for me. What version of StyleFrame are you using? `import StyleFrame ;  print(StyleFrame._version_)`

Comment: version 0.1.5 is what I am using

Comment: I guess it looks like when I open the excel file the column width is visually changed.  But when I right click the column and select `column width` my specification is not what it says

Comment: Yeah, the actual width values in Excel seem to consistently be 0.62 less than the desired. You can try to exaggerate and set a very large width just to verify that your changes are actually being saved to the file. I'll look into it and fix it for the next version :)

Comment: Yep, for me it is .76 less than expected, but still consistent.

Comment: This is related to the way Excel stores column widths: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/293/column-width-issue#comment-10400299

Unfortunately there's not something that openpy (which styleframe uses) or styleframe can do.

Comment: What about [this approach](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html)?

Comment: any ideas on how to remove the column headers when saving the file with the method I posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your question on how to remove the headers, you can simply pass `header=False` to `to_excel`:

`sf.to_excel(excel_writer=excel_writer, header=False)`.

Note that this will still result with the first line of the table being bold.
If you don't want that behavior you can update to 0.1.6 that I just released.